# spring boot cloud app, cosmos db findOne PropertyReferenceException

Tags: java, spring-boot, azure-cosmosdb

I am trying to make CosmosDB working in my spring boot cloud app.

Working with those docs: [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/java/spring-framework/how-to-guides-spring-data-cosmosdb)

but I see an error:

> Caused by:
> org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No
> property findOne found for type Test!

My TestRepository code:

```
import com.azure.spring.data.cosmos.repository.CosmosRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface TestRepository extends CosmosRepository<Test, String> {
    Iterable<Test> findByFirstName(String firstName);

    long countByFirstName(String firstName);

    Test findOne(String id, String lastName);
}
```

it works fine when I comment out findOne method, dunno how to fix it.

thanks

Comment: Looking at your entity name it's clear that you are not exactly following the documentation. Can you double check all your changes?

Answer (score 1):

ah, not sure why its wrong in docs ( or maybe there is some different config ), but renaming this findOne method helps:

```
Test findOneByIdAndLastName(String id, String lastName);
```